# Disabling contextual menu when long clicking text in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

I want to disable the default Contextual ActionBar (containing the Copy-Paste-Select All items) when long clicking a word in an EditText. This bar:

[image]

I tried to use the following code, but the problem with this code is that the selection handles don't appear anymore:

```
editText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new Callback() {
      @Override
      public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {        
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        // I also tried menu.clear() but has the same behavior.
        return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Does any one know how to disable the contextual actionbar and keep the selection handles?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by keeping selection handles without Contexual ActionBar ?

Comment: @jimmy0251 I will show a floating toolbar instead of a contextual action bar.

Comment: I need achieve this as well. Did you find out a way to do it?

Comment: @SoundConception added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long hours of research, unfortunately the only way to do this is by forking TextView & EditText code and changing its code directly.